# jQuery get selected option value (not the text, but the attribute 'value')

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

Okay, I have this code:

```
<select name="selector" id="selector">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

And I'd like to get the value of the option selected.
Example:
'Option 2' is selected, and the value of it is '2'. The '2' is the value I need to get and not 'Option 2'.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

**04/2020: Corrected old answer**

Use [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) pseudo selector on the selected options and then use the [.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get the value of the option.

```
$('select[name=selector] option').filter(':selected').val()
```

**Side note**: Using filter is better then using `:selected` selector directly in the first query.

If inside a change handler, you could use simply `this.value` to get the selected option value. See demo for more options.

```js
//ways to retrieve selected option and text outside handler
console.log('Selected option value ' + $('select option').filter(':selected').val()); 
console.log('Selected option value ' + $('select option').filter(':selected').text());

$('select').on('change', function () {
  //ways to retrieve selected option and text outside handler
  console.log('Changed option value ' + this.value);
  console.log('Changed option text ' + $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1" selected>1 - Text</option>
  <option value="2">2 - Text</option>
  <option value="3">3 - Text</option>
  <option value="4">4 - Text</option>
</select>
```

**Old answer:**

**Edit:** As many pointed out, this does not returns the selected option value.

~~Use [**.val**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the selected option. See below,

```
$('select[name=selector]').val()~~
```

Comment: Do ur test:
`$('select[name=selector]').change(function() { alert($(this).val()); });`

Comment: Note that if the selected option has no `value` attribute specified, the label (i.e. `<option>label</option>`) will be returned. Might not always be what you want. Of course, in most applications, value is specified.

Comment: Why is using `filter` better? Also why does `.val()` not work? It seems to work at least in Chrome. It's not clear from the comments. Thanks for your help!

Comment: for me .val() seems to work fine, any reason not to use it?

Comment: This doesn't work, but if you use `.find` instead of `.filter` you might have success :wink:

Comment: Why is this? -> Side note: Using filter is better then using :selected selector directly in the first query.

Answer (score 138):

I just wanted to share my experience

For me,

`$('#selectorId').val()`

returned null.

I had to use

`$('#selectorId option:selected').val()`

Comment: Was that browser specific case? Did the newest version of chrome not allow it, or was it IE that didnt support it?

Comment: It was in the newest version of Chrome. Maybe also in Firefox, but not sure.

Comment: Not sure why `$('#selectorId option:selected').val()` didn't worked for me. Instead I used `$('select option:selected').val()`

Comment: @Francisco The problem is that `$('select option:selected').val()` will take the value of the first selector in the HTML code. Whereas with `$('#selectorId option:selected').val()` you can have the value of the selector which id you specified. Double check for typos. Here is an example that shows what I just said: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nqgqyz

Answer (score 25):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/764W9/)**

`.val()` will get the value.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add an id to your select. Then:
`$('#selectorID').val()`

Comment: i have the id added, just forgot to add it here.

Comment: From what I've read using an ID as a selector is the fastest method.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data= $('select').find('option:selected').val();
});
```

or

```
var data= $('select').find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use `jquery` as follows

**SCRIPT**

```
  $('#IDOfyourdropdown').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
  });
```

FIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qRpfx/1/)

Answer (score 3):

For a select like this

```
<select class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="list-name" style="width: auto;">
   <option id="0">CHOOSE AN OPTION</option>
   <option id="127">John Doe</option>
   <option id="129" selected>Jane Doe</option>
```

... you can get the id this way:

```
$('#list-name option:selected').attr('id');
```

Or you can use value instead, and get it the easy way...

```
<select class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="list-name" style="width: auto;">
   <option value="0">CHOOSE AN OPTION</option>
   <option value="127">John Doe</option>
   <option value="129" selected>Jane Doe</option>
```

like this:

```
$('#list-name').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

One of my options didn't have a value: `<option>-----</option>`. I was trying to use `if (!$(this).val()) { .. }` but I was getting strange results. Turns out if you don't have a `value` attribute on your `<option>` element, it returns the text inside of it instead of an empty string. If you don't want `val()` to return anything for your option, make sure to add `value=""`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(document ).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=selectorname]').change(function() { 
     alert($(this).val());});
 });
```

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Comment: @paper1111 this is simple functions. I can explain if this is needed. 

$('select[name = here is select box name])

.change() - function its mean that when we change select box option function will be work.

$(this).val() - it return selected option value

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#myOptions').change(function() {
  var value = $("#myOptions option:selected").val();
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<select name="selector" id="myOptions">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

this code work very well for me:
this return the value of selected option.
     $('#select_id').find('option:selected').val();

Answer (score 1):

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/jquery-get-selected-value-and-text-from-dropdown-selectbox/)**

Use jQuery **val()** to **GET** Selected Value and and **text()** to GET Option Text.

```
    <select id="myDropDown" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select Value 0</option>
        <option value="8">Option value 8</option>
        <option value="5">Option value 5</option>
        <option value="4">Option value 4</option>
    </select>
```

**Change Event** on Select Dropdown

```
        $("#myDropDown").change(function () {

            // Fetching Value
            console.log($(this).val());

            // Fetching Text
            console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());

            alert('Value: '+$(this).val()+' | Text: '+$(this).find('option:selected').text());
        });
```

**Button Click**

```
        $("button").click(function () {

        // Fetching Value
            console.log($("#myDropDown").val());

    // Fetching Text
            console.log($('#myDropDown option:selected').text());

            alert('Value: '+$("#myDropDown").val()+' | Text: '+$('#myDropDown option:selected').text());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working better. Try it.

`let value = $("select#yourId option").filter(":selected").val();`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example:

```
    <select class="element select small" id="account_name" name="account_name"> 

        <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>           
        <option value="paypal" >Paypal</option>
        <option value="webmoney" >Webmoney</option>

    </select>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){ 
             $('#account_name').change(function(){
               alert($(this).val());                                                          
             });
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectorID').val();
```

*OR*

```
$('select[name=selector]').val();
```

*OR*

```
$('.class_nam').val();
```

Comment: @FarhadBagherlo "Keep typing" is **not** a useful edit comment! Please summarize your changes, so that readers of the edit history understand what you've done without inspecting every changed character. Thanks!