# Hide a select based on the value of another select

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve to make the visibility of 1 select item dependent of another 1. I thought I could to this with javascript like this:

Head:

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        jQuery("#filepermissiontype").change(function() {           

            if (jQuery(this).val() = "global") {
                jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").hide();
            }else{
                jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").show();
            } 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Elements:

```
    <select id="filepermissiontype" data-placeholder="..." name="filepermissiontype"  class="select" value="<?php echo set_value('filepermissiontype'); ?>">
<option></option>
<option value="global">Everyone</option>
<option value="company">Company</option>
<option value="companyandchildren">Company & children</option>                                          
</select>

<select id="filepermissioncompanyid" data-placeholder="..." name="filepermissioncompanyid"  class="select" value="<?php echo set_value('filepermissioncompanyid'); ?>">
<option></option>
<option value="1">Corp 1</option>
<option value="2">Corp 2</option>
<option value="2">Corp 3</option>                                           
</select>
```

With this, I expect that when I select global in the first select, the second select would disappear, but this is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: changed if (jQuery(this).val() = "global") to if (jQuery(this).val() == "global")

Answer (score 1):

you're using an assignment operator when you meant to use a comparison operator. simple mistake. change to...

```
if (jQuery(this).val() == "global"){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is not correct:

```
if(jQuery(this).val() = "global"){...}
```

Should be

```
if(jQuery(this).val() == "global"){...}
```

Or

```
if(jQuery(this).val() === "global"){...}
```

Keep in mind that assignment `=` is not the same as **[comparison](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)** for equality `==` or strict equality `===`

**EDIT**: according to the comments below, the OP has problems getting the value of the select option. Try doing the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        jQuery("select[id=filepermissiontype]").change(function() {           
            if (jQuery(this).val() = "global") {
                jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").hide();
            }else{
                jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").show();
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please see this **[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089944/jquery-get-selected-option-value-not-the-text-but-the-attribute-value)** as a future reference.

Comment: Hi, I tried that (stupid mistake of me) but that does not change a thing in the result. So even with if (jQuery(this).val() == "global"), the second select is always there

Comment: Then break it down, `console.log(jQuery(this).val());` should help to identify the root of your problems within `jQuery("#filepermissiontype").change`. If the values are the same and the comparison works, then something is interfering with the `.hide()` and `.show()` jQuery functionality

Comment: Hi,
I've added it like this:

 `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
        jQuery(document).ready(function (){
            jQuery("#filepermissiontype").change(function() {           
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());
                if (jQuery(this).val() == "global") {
                    jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").hide();
                }else{
                    jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").show();
                } 
            });
        });
  </script>`
But I don't see anything in the console

Comment: @mitch2k I have updated my answer with a fix you needed. Instead of using the selector `jQuery("#filepermissiontype")`, I used `jQuery("select[id=filepermissiontype]")` give that a try

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately even with == and jQuery("select[id=filepermissiontype]") it is not working.

Comment: Now I added in head:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">  
  console.log("TEST");
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){

        jQuery("select[id=filepermissiontype]").change(function() {           
            if (jQuery(this).val() == "global") {
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());
                jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").hide();
            }else{
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());
                jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").show();
            } 
        });
    });
</script>`
But don't see anything in my Chrome console :s

Comment: @mitch2k first of all try to keep all your jQuery code inside your `jQuery(document).ready(function (){ `, meaning your `console.log("TEST"); ` as well. Second, your code works now see this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AGE/hz70oq3p/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. There must be something else on the codeigniter view that is interfering with this js. I have to put it between the head tag, right?

Comment: I would always add my '<script>' tags after my '<body>' tag, also preferably after any other external libraries too which are being used such as the jquery one. I can definitely not tell if code igniter is the source of your issues though, but you should consider debugging you code.

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake '=' is assignment, == for compare

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function (){
     jQuery("#filepermissiontype").change(function() {           

     if (jQuery(this).val() == "global") {
             jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").hide();
        }else{
            jQuery("#filepermissioncompanyid").show();
        } 
    });
});
```