# How to get the the value of a select option

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value of a select option?

```
<select id="geo_level_one">
  <option class="" value=""></option>
  <option label="AAA" value="0">AAA</option>
  <option label="BBB" value="1">BBB</option>
  <option label="CCC" value="2">CCC</option>
</select>
```

The value of the label `BBB` is `1`. How can I use jQuery to return this value?

Comment: Not so complicated to google: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: Do you mean that when the `BBB` option is selected you want to get the value of `1`? Or that you want to get the value from the element with the `BBB` text?

Comment: Also note that inventing your own attributes (`label` in this case) means that your HTML is invalid. If you want to store custom meta data with an element, use a ` data-*` attribute

Comment: Hi Rory McCrossan! If I query for the label "AAA" I should get 0, if I query for the label "BBB" I should get 1, if I query for the label "CCC" I should get 2. Thanks

Comment: @André Ok - I added an answer for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get selected option value (not the text, but the attribute 'value')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089944/jquery-get-selected-option-value-not-the-text-but-the-attribute-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that `label` is not a valid attribute for an `option` element. To store custom metadata in an element, use a `data-*` attribute, eg `data-label`.

> If I query for the label "AAA" I should get 0, if I query for the label "BBB" I should get 1, if I query for the label "CCC" I should get 2

Given this statement, you can use the attribute selector to find the required `option` and the `val()` to get its `value`. Try this:

```js
var query = 'BBB';
var val = $('#geo_level_one option[data-label="' + query + '"]').val();

console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="geo_level_one">
  <option class="" value=""></option>
  <option data-label="AAA" value="0">AAA</option>
  <option data-label="BBB" value="1">BBB</option>
  <option data-label="CCC" value="2">CCC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Rory McCrossan, the website is not in my control. I cannot change from "label" to "data-label". Any other alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: In which case use `option[label="' + ...` although you may have issues in older versions of IE.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Could you use the `:contains` selector here?

Comment: @JonathanBowman no, as that searches the innerText of the element

Comment: Would the inner text be the same as the `label` attribute, though?

Comment: Very true for the OPs example, so in that case yes. Although his question was specifically about using the `label` attribute.

Comment: Ah, gotcha - yeah using `:contains` on the option elements would work as long as the label attribute and text were the same, which isn't a given.

Answer (score 3):

The `val()` method will return what you're looking for! So, `$("#geo_level_one").val();`

You can change the dropdown here and look at the console to see it in action. I updated it to show getting the label without using invalid attributes - good catch, Rory McCrossan!

```js
$("#geo_level_one").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).find("option:selected").text());
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="geo_level_one">
<option class="" value=""></option>
<option value="0">AAA</option>
<option value="1">BBB</option>
<option value="2">CCC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Upvote simply for giving the `change()` event handler - which is the most crucial part really.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Where is he saying when the select changes? He only wants to know the value of the `select`, read the question.

Comment: Hi, I do not need to use ".change". I only want to query the values of the options. If I query for the label "AAA" I should get 0, if I query for the label "BBB" I should get 1, if I query for the label "CCC" I should get 2.

Answer (score 1):

Easy as:

```
$( "#geo_level_one" ).val();
```

Will return the current selected value.

Documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
var value = $('#geo_level_one').val();
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to explain the code you post. This allows newer developers to understand how the code works and what it does.