# javascript get value of dropdown that is on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this html code

```
  <select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" 
   data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">

<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="blu" class="attached enabled">blu</option>
<option value="red" class="attached enabled">red</option>
  </select>
```

so i want to add a javascript code under this or before this and when i will select any option in dropdown it will show an alert with the option i selected

so i cannot edit this html i need just another javascript code that will detected change of this and will show alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, actually, considering OP's chosen tags, they don't want to do it without jQuery. So it's not a duplicate of that question, but of this one: [jQuery get selected option value (not the text, but the attribute 'value')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089944/jquery-get-selected-option-value-not-the-text-but-the-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it (using jQuery):

```js
$('#pa_color').on('change', function(){
   alert($(this).val());
})
```

```js
$('#pa_color').on('change', function(){
   alert($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" 
   data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">

<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="blu" class="attached enabled">blu</option>
<option value="red" class="attached enabled">red</option>
  </select>
```

---

If you want to do it without jQuery:

```js
document.getElementById("pa_color").onchange = function(e) { 
  alert(e.target.value)
};
```

Alternatively, you could just place `onchange="alert(this.value)"` on the `<select>` tag itself:

```html
<select onchange="alert(this.value)">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="blu">blu</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
</select>
```