# How use Select Option in Watson Conversation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to insert the select options tag into my conversation, to make it more simple to the user. I did this:

[image: Conversation]

And in the index.js:

```
function selected(){
switch($('#selected option:selected').val()){
    case 01:
       alert("01");
        break;
    case 02:
        alert("02");
        break;
}
};
```

But it doesn't recognize the option selected. I tried without the function selected() (only with switch case), but it didn't worked.. Can somebody help me please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you answer to my question connected to your problem here ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787117/how-to-create-a-form-builder-with-watson-conversation-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787117/how-to-create-a-form-builder-with-watson-conversation-dialog)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your HTML inside the Advanced context have something you miss.

In your HTML in `onselect` your typed `:`, but, for use [onselect](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmwkbaj.php) and call one function you have to use `onselect="nameFnction()"`

See [one](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onselect.asp) simple example inside MDN to use this tag:

```
<input type="text" onselect="myFunction()" value="Hello world!">
```

Now, see [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) example for works fine according the choice:

```
<select>
  <option onclick="doSomethingA(this);">A</option>
  <option onclick="doSomethingB(this);">B</option>
  <option onclick="doSomethingC(this);">C</option>
</select>
```

And with [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089944/jquery-get-selected-option-value-not-the-text-but-the-attribute-value) (Your id is select and not selected):

```
$('#select option:selected').val()
```

Comment: Hi Sayuri, I am trying to implement date picker in my IBM watson dialog response. I know that HTML code could be inserted as TEXT in response but how I am not able to figure out. Please help me out with some code snippet. I am not a UI person too.

Comment: Hi @Kumar, that would be a different question and with some updates that Watson Assistant had in the past months. I would advise you to create a new Question. You can ping me

Comment: Yes, I created one new question. Please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204579/use-html-date-picker-in-ibm-watson-conversation-dialog-to-get-date-as-input-from?noredirect=1#comment108277496_61204579

Comment: Thank U for time.