# use HTML date picker in IBM watson conversation dialog to get date as input from user

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to use   `<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">` to display a calendar to be selected by user on IBM dialog. So, when this calendar will ask for date in the chat bot and then after user selecting the date, it should store the selected date as  variable or any context variable. 
How I have to implement it in IBM Watson chatbot.
Thanks

Comment: Watson Assistant returns text and, depending on the interface, may return some HTML. What interface are you using? Web chat integration supports HTML

Comment: Default interface of IBM Chat Bot.

Comment: @data_henrik I can see the date picker and select the date but how to I further move to store in to a selected context variable?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how your front-end app is built to call IBM Watson API. Trying to be more generic, you would need to do:

First, you would need to add the `html` syntax into your answer/response node on Watson Conversation:

```html
Please select your date: <br /> 
<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
```

And in your front-end code (probably `index.html` that contains your UI), you would need a function to identify what was selected, e.g:

```js
document.getElementById("birthday").addEventListener("change", function() {
    let inputDate = this.value;
    let ifYouWantEntireDateFormat = new Date(inputDate);
    console.log(inputDate); // 2020-04-20
    console.log(ifYouWantEntireDateFormat); //e.g. Mon April 20 2020 00:00:00 etc
});
```

You could also use `querySelector` function. In addition, if no value is selected it will return "Invalid date"

With all that in mind, you also need to know that Watson API accepts the `payload` having the `context` variables on it, which is what you need. I would recommend checking the [API docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#send-user-input-to-assistant) first to understand more. But according to what I understood, your payload might be similar to:

```js
const AssistantV2 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v2');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const assistant = new AssistantV2({
  version: '2020-04-01',
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: '{apikey}',
  }),
  url: '{url}',
});

assistant.message({
  assistantId: '{assistant_id}',
  sessionId: '{session_id}',
  input: {
    'message_type': 'text',
    'text': 'Hello',
    'options': {
      'return_context': true
    }
  },
  context: {
    'global': {
      'myDatePicker': inputDate,
      'system': {
        'user_id': 'my_user_id'
      }
    },
    'skills': {
      'main skill': {
        'user_defined': {
          'account_number': '123456'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.result, null, 2));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

**Note** The `context` is included in message responses only if you `return_context=true` in the message request.

**Important links:**

- Input type Date - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)
- Watson Assistant [API doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#send-user-input-to-assistant) - IBM Watson

Comment: Hey, thank u so much for detailed answer. However, I am only using preview link that is integrated to some website page, nothing else. So, basically I am using default UI that is shown in preview link. What you are suggesting is something I have a explicit front end for user.

Comment: So when I use preview link , I can get ChatBot to play. There I can use option and text as input provided default but how can I use DatePicker that is to be set as response for Dialogue Node.