# jQuery / selecting option element

Tags: jquery, events

My `Producer` model has `Id` and `Name`

`Movie` model has `Title` and `Producer` as property.

My `index.html` :

```
<select id="selectMovieProducer">
                        
</select>
```

I have following `event`

```
$("body").ready(function(){
    var requestUrl = host + port + moviesEndPoint;
    $.getJSON(requestUrl, setMovies)
});
```

`setMovies` function from the code above generates (appends) a table with all movies, and then a `<option>` element for each `Producer` (appends to `<Select>` from `HTML`). Each `<option>` has `value` property set to `Producer`'s `Id` while displaying its `Name` (in a dropdown/select).

Im working on this `event` to `POST` new movie:

```
 $("#movieForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        var title = $("#movieTitle").val();
        var genre = $("#movieGenre").val();
        var premierYear = $("#moviePremierYear").val();
        var producerId = ???    
});
```

How do i get/access `value` property of the **selected** `<option>` ?
I need it so i can create a movie object and send it to my post method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089959/8177490 Did you try this to get the selected value of the option?

Comment: @digitalsuite.net I was not aware of this. His 'recommended' way of selecting is too confusing. I will use his alternative $("option:selected").val();

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089959/8177490

or

```
var producerId = $("option:selected").val();
```