# how to generate random value in input box in php using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, random

i have a website done in php, which has a form for user to select a certain data, on selection of the data, after that user has the option to generate random value, so the random value should start with the select box value and some random number, so far i did the following:

```js
  function Random() {
          var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
          document.getElementById('tb').value = rnd;
      }
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="customer" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option value="">Select Customer</option>
  <?php
                                                            foreach($listcustomers as $valw){?>
    <option value="<?=$valw->name?>">
      <?=$valw->name?>
    </option>
    <?php }?>

</select>

<input type="button" onclick="Random();" class="btn btn-outline-warning" value="GENERATE">
<input type="text" name="sku" class="form-control" id="tb" placeholder="SKU" value="" required>
```

this is generating random number on button click, but how do i start the random number with the value of user selected value in selectbox, can anyone please tell me, thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `jquery` involved? in `Random()`, get the selected option from your `<select>` and prepend it to your random number

Comment: @brombeer can u please show how to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery get selected option value (not the text, but the attribute 'value')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089944/jquery-get-selected-option-value-not-the-text-but-the-attribute-value)

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Is this a Javascript problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do is get the value of the selected option in JavaScript and add it as the start value before your random number. Your `Random()` function can be like:

```js
function Random() {
    var userValueElement = document.getElementById("userValue");
    var userValue = userValueElement.options[userValueElement.selectedIndex].text;
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
    document.getElementById('tb').value = userValue + rnd;
}
```

Notice that I am getting the `select` element with the help of `id`. You can add `id` to your `select` element:

```html
<select id="userValue" class="form-control" name="customer" aria-label="Default select example">
...
</select>
```